# For a ring if we have: $\forall a\in R$ with $za=az=z$ does that mean $z=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> For a ring if we have: $\forall a\in R$ with $za=az=z$ does that mean $z=0$?

If we have $x+z=x$ for all $x\in R$ ($x+z=z+x$ as it is a ring) then we show z is unique and call it 0. For 0 it is true that $0a=a0=0$ (which is one of my favourite statements, as it shows the multiplicative identity and additive one are different (or the same for a ring of 1 element))

Is it true that an element $z\in R$ such that $az=za=z$ $\forall a\in R\implies z=0$

If the ring has unity then I can see this is true (in the sense that the multiplication table wont be able to have the intersecting-on-the-diagonal row of 0s and es it'd need to define, they'd "overlap") but that isn't formal.

I'd like to formally prove this.

Comment: Well $0z=0$....

Comment: What does "$\forall a\in R$ with $za=az=z$" mean? It seems like a fragment of a mathematical statement, not something that could stand alone as the premise of a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly if it holds for all $a \in R$, it holds for $a = 0$.

Then your statement becomes $0z = z0 = z$, but $0z = 0$ (by definition of $0$), so $z = 0$.

Comment: Yes I get that, but must z be 0, that is if we find a z such that $\forall a\in R$ we have $za=az=z$ have we found the 0 of the ring?

Comment: @AlecTeal $0z = z$, so $z = 0$.

Comment: @AlecTeal: I added another sentence of explanation

Comment: @Goos thanks, I should have seen 0z=z, and thought "0z=0" thus z=0

Comment: @AlecTeal I'm writing up an answer where we assume this holds for any $a \ne 0$.  By the way, in general you should wait a day or two before accepting an answer.

Comment: @Goos please don't stop writing that answer, also I accepted because if I don't people moan at me! Rep is pretty arbitrary (once you cross the threshold to comment) so don't worry too much.

Comment: @AlecTeal Ha, I'm not worried about the rep, and I think you accepted the right answer.  And of course you should accept an answer *at some point*.  But it doesn't hurt to wait a few days if your problem is nontrivial.  See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2554/68107).

Answer (score 4):

Of course trivially, if $a = 0$ then $0z = z$ so $z = 0$.
But let's exclude this trivial case and suppose $az = za = z$ for all *nonzero* $a$.  Then must $z = 0$?

There are two cases.

- First, suppose $e + e \ne 0$, where $e$ is the identity.
  Then choose $a = e + e$, and we have $z + z = z$ by distributivity, hence $z = 0$.
- Otherwise, $e + e = 0$.  Then for any $x, y \ne 0$,
  $$
  (x + y)z = xz + yz = z + z = (e + e)z = 0
  $$
  If $x + y \ne 0$, then $(x + y)z = z$ so this implies $z = 0$.
  Otherwise, we get that $x + y = 0$ for all nonzero $x, y \in R$.  Adding $y$ to both sides, $x = y$, and the ring must consist of only two elements.  We have $R = \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$, and $z = 1$, and indeed $az = z$ for all nonzero $a$.  This is the only exception.

Comment: In fact $z+z=0$ even when $R$ is a ring without unity. For if $z\ne0$, then $z^2=z$. So $z+z=z^2+z^2=z(z+z)$ implies either $z+z=0$ or it is nonzero and $z+z=z(z+z)=z$, the latter being a contradiction. In particular, you do not have to split between two cases like you have above.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Thanks for the input and the cleaner approach!